# is_user_logged_in() returns different values on different pages

Tags: cookies, user-access, authentication

On most of my site, is_user_logged_in() works perfectly.

On two pages with similar custom templates set, this incorrectly returns FALSE. The user can navigate back to other pages where it works correctly with no issue.

In effect, a user will login, and see "log out" as appropriate. When they navigate to specific pages only, they instead see "log in".

I've done some testing and am not sure what is causing this. A few things I've tried:

- Removing references to global user variables in the theme files.
- Forcing the cookie directory in wp-config through define(
  'COOKIEPATH', '/' )
- Disabling likely offending plugins.

I don't have a good understanding of WP functions/calls that might potentially be causing this. I'd be very grateful for any pointers towards likely trouble areas or tips for troubleshooting. What could possibly be happening in the theme templates to disrupt is_user_logged_in()? Am I looking in the right place?

Answer (score 0):

OK, figured out my own problem. In case anyone else stumbles across this and has similar issues:

The problem was due to incomplete/incorrect implementation of SSL. I had recently moved everything to SSL (and setup both wp-config and .htaccess to force use of https).

This created a problem for some links to pages that were not updated to include the 's' in https. WP would still display the page correctly, but the cookies would break, therefore causing the incorrect return of is_user_logged_in().

The solution was embarrassingly simple: update the links to https.